# Windows Store Apps: application terminated due to low system resources

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have an application that when switched gets terminated and all the session data are lost.

I check the Event Viewer app and found the following info message:

> Package [My application package GUID] was terminated due to low system
>   resources

What can be the reason for this and how to solve it ?

Comment: You app eats the entire available memory?

Comment: I don't know, I checked the task manager, it takes about 50 MB then lowers to 27 then just disappears !

Answer (score 1):

Did you test your application by Windows App Certification Kit?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx

Maybe this test could be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: I ran the certification kit, and it passed, nothing failed.

Comment: Are you using any mobile, web services or anything like that?

Comment: Yes the application displays some data retrieved from a web service

Comment: Okay, I got the exact same problem right know like you. Are you sure your web service still availible?

Comment: This problem happens randomly, maybe when there are lots of apps running in the same time, I really can't understand the reasong

Comment: As I guess that problem is about your web service. Where are you hosting your web service? I suggest you to open a Trial Windows Azure account and move your web service to there. Windows 8 apps are crashing when they got no answer or corrupt answer from a web service. Give a shot to Windows Azure services, I believe that'll fix your problem.

Comment: No, the web service returns the data without any errors, I believe it's a memory issue

Answer (score 0):

You may be have lots of "Resource packages". Try delete some of them, and clean any additional system resources. 
Or it can be having by bad design of application lifecycle. You can check it out [from here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx)